# Positioning the axis label on polar plot / color coded legend

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to make the Distance label originate at the center of the plot and there to be a legend which describes the change in color based on the inputted change in temperature.

Here's the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

theta = np.array(data["ra"])
dist_arr = np.array(data["dist"])
colors = np.log10(np.array(data["T"]))
area = np.array(data["M_V"])**2


fig = plt.figure(dpi=300)
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='polar')
c = ax.scatter(theta, dist_arr,c=colors, s=area, cmap='hsv', alpha=0.75, label='Stars')
ax.set_title("Stars < 20 light years away", va='bottom')
ax.set_ylabel('Distance (ly)', size=12, loc='bottom')
ax.legend(loc='best', scatterpoints=1)

plt.show()
```

**Here's the graph currently:**

[image: Polar Plot Output]

Comment: Could you provide a few rows of your dataset or a link to the data for testing perposes?

Comment: name component ra dec class sub-class V M_V T dist
"Proxima Centauri" C 217.42499999999998 -61.31666666666667 M 5.5 11.01 15.45 2985.0 4.22
"Alpha Centauri" A 219.92499999999998 -59.166666666666664 G 2.0 -0.01 4.34 5840.0 4.4
"Alpha Centauri" B 219.92499999999998 -59.166666666666664 K 0.0 1.35 5.7 5200.0 4.4
"Barnard's Star" - 269.45 4.7 M 5.0 9.54 13.24 3050.0 5.94
"Wolf 359" - 164.125 7.016666666666667 M 6.0 13.45 16.56 2920.0 7.8
"Lalande 21185" - 165.825 35.96666666666667 M 2.0 7.49 10.46 3440.0 8.31

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution is the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
from math import pi

theta = np.array(data["ra"])
dist_arr = np.array(data["dist"])
colors = np.log10(np.array(data["T"]))
area = np.array(data["M_V"])**2

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6), dpi=100)
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='polar')

ax.set_theta_offset(pi/2)
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
ax.set_rlabel_position(0)
plt.yticks([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10'], color="grey", size=10)
plt.ylim(0,10)

c = ax.scatter(theta, dist_arr, c=colors, s=area, cmap='hsv', alpha=0.75, label='Stars')

# make colorbar
fig.colorbar(c, label="T")

ax.set_title("Stars < 20 light years away", va='bottom')
ax.set_ylabel('Distance (ly)', size=12, loc='bottom')

plt.show()
```

Returns

[image]